# Find pip requirements that require a different index-url

Tags: python, pip

I have a list of requirements in a `requirements.txt` file. Some of these requirements are dependent on a private `index-url`. How can I extract them so that I only download ones that cannot be downloaded by the default public pip index-url?

To download them all I do this:

```
pip download -r requirements.txt --extra-index-url="https://myprivatepackages.com/+simple" -d .packages/
```

Comment: Do you mean that you do not know which ones are private and which ones are private? And are you asking how to automatically sort them into public and private dependencies somehow?

Comment: @sinorac exactly!

Comment: I see. Then I don't know. Maybe [dephell](https://pypi.org/project/dephell/) can help indirectly.